# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fltkd.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to learn C++ with MS Visual Studio 2015. I figured out how the header files work with Bjorne Stroustup's Programming Principles of C++

When I try to build this error comes up:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'fltkd.lib'

My ftk installation was a success and I closed it after to work on the example in appendix D.

I also tried everything I searched for including going to

```
project<properties<linker<input<additional dependencies
```

and listing all the necessary `lib` files as indicated in the book.

Comment: Have you searched your disk for the fltkd.lib?

Comment: hi MarcinG. I already copied and paste it into visual studio/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory that has `fltk.lib` should be included in the directories list - the `fltk-x.x.x\FL` and `fltk-x.x.x\GL` should be available during the build , so put those 2 directories in the VC++ proj - path for libs.

Comment: check this link - http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk2/Cxx/FltkInstallVC/FltkInstallVC.html

Comment: its weird that I do not have the GL file. I'm using fltk-1.1.10, not sure if i'm affected because of the version. .

Comment: Why don't you move to 1.3.3? - check the warning on this page - http://www.fltk.org/software.php

Comment: thanks abhi for the link.

i did exactly what you said and installed the tar(i previously didn't because i thought it would only apply to Linux OS and will be troublesome for Windows).

then I followed the instructions and copied the FL and GL, only thing that's different is that my Visual Studio environment is located at `foo\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC`

so after that I was able to build and compile

Answer (score 0):

I know this might come pretty late, but here I am in September 2019 following the same book and having had the same error.

In my case, the solution for the 'cannot open fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib' was another:

- instead of copying and pasting like this:

```
fltkd.lib wsock32.lib comctl32.lib fltkjpegd.lib fltkimagesd.lib
```

you should try pasting each .lib on its own line, like this:

```
fltkd.lib
wsock32.lib 
comctl32.lib 
fltkjpegd.lib 
fltkimagesd.lib
```

That did it for me.

P.S: I'm surprised the author didn't include this in an errata, as I was on the point of giving up after trying to solve this for a few days (I actually gave it a break of 2 weeks and today I found this solution)